# BouncyCastle encrypted file is forcing passphrase to be entered

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

I have a bit of a peculiar issue with BouncyCastle.

What is happening is I am using a public key to encrypt a text file, which is then being transmitted to a third party.  When they attempt to auto-decrypt the file at their end (using Globalscape - not sure of the version), the process fails, asking for a passphrase to unlock the secret key.

If I do the same process, but encrypt the file using GPG4Win with the same key, they are not getting the same issue.

This is the code doing the encryption:

```
private static bool EncryptFile(Stream outputStream, string fileName, PgpPublicKey encKey, bool withIntegrityCheck)
        {
            try
            {
                var bytes = PgpUtils.CompressFile(fileName, CompressionAlgorithmTag.Uncompressed);

                // encrypt using AES-256
                var encryptedDataGenerator = new PgpEncryptedDataGenerator(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.Aes256, withIntegrityCheck, new SecureRandom());
                encryptedDataGenerator.AddMethod(encKey);

                using (var cOutStream = encryptedDataGenerator.Open(outputStream, bytes.Length))
                {
                    cOutStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Trace.TraceError($"Exception in EncryptFile: {e}");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I admit I am a little lost here.  Can anyone point out what I am missing?  Or should I be asking the third party to dig further?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is more a high level approach  to pin down the underlying problem:

You are encrypting with a Public Key. That means the recipient needs the matching Private Key.

It *looks* like the recipient has the key because else the client *should* complain about a missing private key, not about a missing passphrase for the key.

Check the following (from easy to not so easy)

- Can the recipient decrypt when he enters the passphrase? If yes, configure the client to save the passphrase.
- Try to decrypt with your local gpg
- Are you sure that the client has the private key? If not, make sure that the client has the private key (Maybe you use different keys with your Code and gpg4win)
- Can the client handle the encryption method **at all**? I.e. does the client know how to decrypt the message format you send?("did it ever work?" - I have no experience with Globalscape)

Comment: Yes, the client can successfully and auto decrypt files that have been encrypted with the same public key when the encryption has been done using Gpg4win (or more specifically, Kleopatra).

Comment: Can you decrypt the files you create with gpg or gpg4win?